# Received email that iOS development Certificate was revoked, what is it mean?

Tags: unity, xcode, appstore, build-process

I'm trying to make a .ipa in Xcode from the build of my project file exported in unity3d. There was two errors in Xcode which are 1."Signing for "Unity-iPhone" requires a development team. Select a development team in the project editor.
2. Code signing is required for product type 'Application' in SDK 'ios 10.1' that I'm resolving so I tried to search in google on how to resolved it. We have already an apple developers account so I set it as the "development team" (step from the tutorial I saw) then when I'm trying to test the solution I did from Product->Archive in Xcode, I received the email and I think it prevent me from making a .ipa file.

I'm not still sure why I received that email. Based from my research, some say that it means I can not longer able to submit updates to the App Store for my application. Can somebody please help me on the reasons why.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When trying to fix your signing issues, Xcode did ask you if you want Xcode to revoke the Certificate for you, which you accepted.

As a result, you have to download the new certificate and add it your KeyChain (by doubble clicking it). Also, all provisioning profiles created with the old certificate became invalid, so yo have to recreate all provisioning profiles and use them.

Comment: Thank you. I also went to my developers dashboard and found out that the development was labeled as "Invalid".